# Unwanted white bar at the bottom sometimes appears, sometimes not

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-xml

I'm trying to create an Android game using Android Studio. 
However when I'm testing the app from the Android Studio(using my phone as a testing device), there's a white bar which appears at the bottom of the screen. If I switch to another activity and then go back to my main activity, the white bar will dissappear.

Here is my Main Activity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context="acevix.gladiators3.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/splash"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="140dp"
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:background="@drawable/play" />

<TextView
    android:text="GLADIATORS PRE-ALPHA V0.0.1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's my styles.xml file, which I've edited in order to remove some UI:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Activity code:

```
package acevix.gladiators3;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MediaPlayer splashbgmusic;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    playButton.setY((float) (height/4.4));
    playButton.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (height / 5.14);
    playButton.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (width / 3.47);



    playButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //Log.d("SIZE", "Height " + view.getHeight() + ", Width: " + view.getWidth());
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayStage.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    splashbgmusic = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.login);
    splashbgmusic.setLooping(true); // Set looping
    splashbgmusic.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
    splashbgmusic.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    splashbgmusic.stop();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    splashbgmusic.stop();
}


@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocas) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocas);
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    if(hasFocas) {
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    }
}
```

}

**UPDATE:** Apparently the problem is caused by the styles.xml file. If I change the "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" to "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar", the white bar won't appear anymore BUT when I switch between activities the blue navigation bar at the top showing the name of the game will appear for a short time and then dissappear.

And here's a youtube video which shows you exactly the problem (annotations included): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEdkXZRdsu0

Comment: Please post your activity code..@Radu

Comment: I've added it into the main code.

Comment: Update: Apparently the problem is caused by the styles.xml file. If I change the "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" to "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar", the white bar won't appear anymore BUT when I switch between activities the blue navigation bar at the top showing the name of the game will appear for a short time and then dissappear.

Comment: What's an other way to restrict the blue navigation bar at the top appear when I switch between activities?

Comment: Changing `NoActionBar` to `DarkActionBar` worked for me with a similar issue where the bar appeared at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:src="@drawable/splash"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />


  <!--  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/splash"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
       /> --> //If above dosent work try this.

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="140dp"
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:background="@drawable/play" />

    <TextView
        android:text="GLADIATORS PRE-ALPHA V0.0.1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

P.S With Reference to your comments

in `onCreate(...)` of your activity write 
`setContentView(R.layout.splash);
 getActionBar().hide();`

or

```
setContentView(R.layout.splash);
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

to hide the `actionbar`

Comment: Same problem; apparently the styles.xml file is causing this (please read the post again). Thanks a lot for trying to help!

Comment: If you have any idea how I can remove the blue navigation bar at the top of the activity please leave an answer here

Comment: I have updated my answer with the code to hide the visible actionbar. Please check if it solves your problem

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot